# PDO postgres return nothing for all queries

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, vagrant

Cannot understand what's wrong.
I use: `vagrant 1.8.5`; `postgresql 9.3.14`; `PHP 5.5.9` (but also trying 7.0)
Vagrant machine: `ubuntu/trusty64`, php and utils from here: `ppa:ondrej/php`

All seems OK but query results.
Test code:

```
$connect = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=template1;host=localhost', 'postgres', 'postgres');

$st = $connect->prepare("SELECT 1")->fetchAll();
var_dump($st);
var_dump( $connect->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS) );
exit();
```

result:

```
array(0) { } string(31) "Connection OK; waiting to send."
```

Comment: you didn't [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see this behaviour because you don't actually execute the query. After `PDO::prepare` you should call `PDOStatement::execute`. So the following code will return the result:

```
$st = $connect->prepare("SELECT 1")
              ->execute()
              ->fetchAll();
```